# Dapper (for .NET) is not substituting a param when trying to Execute a DB query

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

When I `Execute` the following SQL, Dapper is -not- substituting the param .. but just writing that raw to the database.

[image]

(or for some obfuscated exact sql)

```
INSERT INTO
    Blah
SELECT
    Id,
    GETUTCDATE(),
    'Updated Status to WITHDRAWN. JIRA: @JiraTicket. By: admin maintenance task'
FROM
    Blahs
WHERE
     Id = @Id
```

Instead, this is the sameple data inserted to the DB:

```
    Updated Status to WITHDRAWN. JIRA: @JiraTicket. By: admin maintenance task
```

The value of `jiraTicket` == `AAA123`

The code is:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new())
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        var rowsaffected = db.Execute(command, new
        {
            Id = id,
            JiraTicket = jiraTicket
        });

        // snipped some UI displaying logic
    }

    if (!isTestRun)
    {
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

I just don't understand? Why is not substituting?

#### Update 1:

I've also tried this, which gives the same output:

```
DECLARE @Jira VARCHA(20) = @JiraTicket;

INSERT INTO
    Blah
SELECT
    Id,
    GETUTCDATE(),
    'Updated Status to WITHDRAWN. JIRA: @Jira. By: admin maintenance task'
FROM
    Blahs
WHERE
     Id = @Id
```

#### Update 2:

This *does* work, but I feel dirty. Is there a better way, than this?
NOTE: the string substitution as I generate the params....

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new())
{
    using (var db = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        var rowsaffected = db.Execute(command, new
        {
            Id = id,
            JiraTicket = $"Updated Status to WITHDRAWN. JIRA: {jiraTicket} . By: admin maintenance task"
        });

        // snipped some UI displaying logic
    }

    if (!isTestRun)
    {
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is Dapper to know this is a parameterized value to replace versus explicit text in your SQL?

Comment: Oh, it knows... it's inside the string so it's explicit text. Case closed.

Comment: Try straight SQL - `DECLARE @JiraTicket NVARCHAR(50) = 'Test';
SELECT '@JiraTicket'`.  What would you expect there?

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `'blah JIRA: ' + @JiraTicket + 'the rest'`. Dapper's not going to see that parameter buried in a string like that

Comment: By the way, you _really need to_ replace that picture of code with code (just obfuscate the table name, etc).

Comment: Yes @Flydog57 - i've tried doing the `' + @JiraTicket + '` trick also. no luck. Lastly, I used a pic (for the sql) because I wanted to HIGLIGHT the variable _in the middle of some string_. But i've updated the OP for you.

Comment: Also, for the person asking to close this -> please explain why you think it doesn't meet a specific SO guideline, so I can amend as required.

Comment: @Flydog57 also -> you were right also. I just tried _again_ and that worked. I tried that _yesterday_ but I updated _different_ code and then tested against the wrong thing. So it _would_ have worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter marker can't be inside a varchar literal.  If you want the parameter value to be appended to a string, use [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

So it should be:

```
INSERT INTO
    Blah
SELECT
    Id,
    GETUTCDATE(),
    CONCAT('Updated Status to WITHDRAWN. JIRA: ', @JiraTicket, '. By: admin maintenance task')
FROM
    Blahs
WHERE
     Id = @Id
```

Comment:  Brilliant! better than my  Update #2. I'll take it!